# Copy Data from Notepad/ Excel file to Excel file"Column wise"

Tags: php, javascript, excel, notepad++

i want to copy my data from Notepad/Excel file to Excel file "Column wise".

I have my data like

- A1:HELLO NIKI
- A2:P.O.BOX 930, PH 9022
- A3:
- A4:KDSFH DS SDF SDF
- A5:@HY *(DSD)*

Now i want this data as

- A1:HELLO NIKI
- B1:P.O.BOX 930, PH 9022
- C1:
- A2:KDSFH DS SDF SDF
- B2:@HY *(DSD)*

Note:After three column it will break and start from second line

I have around 3000 lines, stored in excel/notepad file. It is not possible to copy/paste all data, so Please suggest. I know PHP very well so if is there any way using PHP. please suggest first.

My Codes Are:-

```
<?php
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$export=$_REQUEST['export'];
$t=$_REQUEST['t'];
if($_REQUEST['go'])
{
$fo=fopen($name,"r");
$fr=fgets($fo);
$fe=fopen($export,"w");
fwrite($fe,$fr);
echo"Data succesfully Inserted";
}
?>
<form>
Enter flie name<input type="text" name="name" /><br />
Enter Export flie name<input type="text" name="export" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="go" value="Go" />
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried _first_. We aren't a free coding service.

Comment: <?php
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$export=$_REQUEST['export'];
$t=$_REQUEST['t'];
if($_REQUEST['go'])
{
 $fo=fopen($name,"r");
 $fr=fgets($fo);
 $fe=fopen($export,"w");
 fwrite($fe,$fr);
 echo"Data succesfully Inserted";
}
?>
<form>
Enter flie name<input type="text" name="name" /><br />
Enter Export flie name<input type="text" name="export" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="go" value="Go" />

Comment: Can you put that code in the question with proper formatting ?

Answer (score 0):

Excel can directly open a CSV file so just re-write the data to another file, comma separated and inserting a newline after every third item.

Answer (score 0):

copy your data into A1 on Sheet1

Use this formula in Sheet2, starting at A1, copied to the range you want it to fill (e.g. A1:C1000)

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,((ROW()-1)*3)+COLUMN()-1,0)
```

once you start seeing `0`'s, the data has been copied.

Once you have all the data formatted, then highlight columns A,B, and C in Sheet2, Copy and then Paste as values, then you can delete to original data.

Comment: very nice, its working. But now i faced one more problem and that is data repeating. I copied 50000 data "column wise". but i feel some data are duplicate. If i remove duplicate data one by one it will take a lot time. can you please tell "how to remove duplicate data from a column".

Comment: The excel i made "column wise" is using your codes but if i want to copy these data to another sheet, how i do?